# Linear Optimization proof. Duality proof.

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I need help with this problem. The exact problem is in this link http://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F959%2F959d289e-6f26-4e21-875e-bb71f3f5a49f%2Fphprimn1q.png

Sorry for the poor formatting.

Consider the linear programming problem of minimizing $c'x$ subject to $Ax=b, x \geq 0.$ Let $x^*$ be an optimal solution, assumed to exist , and let $p^*$ be an optimal solution to the dual.

(a) Let $\tilde{x}$ be an optimal solution to the primal, when $c$ is replaced by some $\tilde{c}$ . Show that $(\tilde{c} - c)' (\tilde{x} - x^* )  \leq 0.$

(b) Let the cost vector be fixed at c, but suppose that we now change $b$ to $\tilde{b}$, and let $\tilde{x}$ be a corresponding optimal solution to the primal. Prove that $(p^* )'(\tilde{b}-b) \leq c'(\tilde{x} - x^* ).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Both $x^*$ and $\tilde{x}$ are feasible solutions to $Ax=b, x \geq 0$, by definition of $\tilde{x}$, we have

$$\tilde{c}'\tilde{x}\leq \tilde{c} x^*$$

Similarly, by definition of $x^*$, we have

$$c'x^*\leq c'\tilde{x}.$$

Adding the two terms up, we have 
$$\tilde{c}'\tilde{x}+c'x^*\leq \tilde{c} x^*+c'\tilde{x}$$

which is equivalent to $$(\tilde{c}-c)'(\tilde{x}-x^*) \leq 0.$$

(b) $p^*$ is a feasible solution to $p'A \leq c$, by weak duality, we have

$$p^*\tilde{b} \leq c'\tilde{x}.$$

Also, by strong duality $$p^*b=c'x^*.$$

Hence, we have $$p^*\tilde{b}- p^*b \leq c'\tilde{x}-c'x^*.$$

$$p^*(\tilde{b}-b) \leq c'(\tilde{x}-x^*).$$